# Why is rails not finding my table relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'display, title'

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

class GsCollector < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
```

Why can't I do the following in my form for GsCollector?:

```
  <p>
    Model:<br />
    <%= collection_select :gs_collector, :model_id, Product.where("title = 'Some Title'").models.all, :id, :title %>
  </p>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `models' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fef0ac09350>
```

Shouldn't the models method be provided by the relation?  In the console, this works:

```
p = Product.find(4).models
```

But this doesn't:

```
p = Product.where("title = 'some title'").models
```

Not sure what the difference is....

Here's my schema:

```
  create_table "gs_collectors", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "model_id"
    t.integer  "quantity",   :default => 1
    t.string   "housing",    :default => "Base Unit"
    t.string   "hopper"
    t.string   "controller"
    t.boolean  "overbags",   :default => false
    t.datetime "created_at",                          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          :null => false
  end

  create_table "models", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "display"
  end


  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of schema.rb? Maybe you're missing the foreign key.

Comment: Your problem is that `Product.where()` returns an array, several records. Rails does know for which on to fetch all the models. It would be better to use `Product.find_by_title("title").models`.

Comment: The difference between `.where` and `.find` is that `.find` always returns the first record which matches the criteria, thats why it is always directly the record. `.where` allows several records to be returned and therfore always returns an ActiveRecord::Relation which acts as an array containing all matching records.

Comment: @klump, right, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array of objects, collectively called a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. This is due to your `where` search term. Maybe you want something like the following:

```
p = Product.find_by_title('some title').models
```

`where` returns a list of `Products`

`find` returns a single `Product`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationship between Model and GsCollector both ways. You forgot the part in the Model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :gs_collectors
end

class GsCollector < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
end
```

And the real problem is that you can `.models` only on a single record. `Product.where` returns several ones - so use `Product.find_by_title("title").models`